# How to use BrowserStack with Windows Authentication for Active Directory

Tags: browserstack

The BrowserStack website claims that you can still use BrowserStack with Windows Authentication (active directory). Sadly, they failed to explain how to do this. Has anyone set their BrowserStack up to use Active Directory authentication?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of question is best asked of the tool vendor directly.

Comment: Need to asking a vendor and frustrations with not getttig it or not getting it in a timely advice is one of the main reasons for this site.  If the vendor answers I would _still_ post here as an answer to help others who use this site before the painful step of trying to contact the vendor.  you know, you send an email to help@vendor.com and weeks go by.  Come here and get an answer in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only part of [Browserstack's Enterprise plan](https://www.browserstack.com/enterprise-features?ref=pricing), and not their Live, Automate Pro, or Automate Mobile plans.

If you're on the Enterprise plan, then you're better off asking Browserstack directly.